# Is there subscript syntax to extract a diagonal from a 2D Array?

Tags: arrays, raku, matrix-indexing, arrayaccess

I mostly can follow the [syntax](https://docs.perl6.org/language/subscripts#Multiple_dimensions) to 'drill down/slice' into an array with multiple dimensions (and flattening) on the docs page. A very cool feature. For example given:

```
my @a=[[1,2,3],
       [4,5,6],
       [7,8,9]];
```

I can select column 2 of the above using:

```
say @a[0,1,2;1]; #This output (2,5,8)
```

Is it possible to extract the diagonal (1,5,9) in a similar compact syntax?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
say @a[ 0,1,2 ; { $++ } ] ; # (1 5 9)
```

So instead of `1`, which evaluates to `1`, I've used `{ $++ }`, which is a [`Block`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Block).

When Raku encounters a callable code object as a subscript value, it calls it once for each slice it's evaluating, in this case the `0`th, `1`st, and `2`nd rows.

[`$`](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/state#The_$_variable) is an anonymous Scalar state variable.

Comment: ```say @a[0,1,2; { $++ }];``` awesome answer from @raiph - shows why raku rocks ... just to mention that the '.' is optional.

Comment: @p6steve. I too think that it's nice and think that that's because Raku rocks. I've no idea why I decided to write the `.`. Thanks for commenting; I've now removed it because it's very ***un***idiomatic.